# How to save PDF annotations in a separate file?

Tags: pdf, annotation

I aim to annotate PDFs with the annotations stored separately. Okular used to do this.. but sadly [no longer](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=251&t=141963).

Are there any alternatives, either one that stores annotations separately, or a way to split an annotated pdf into the original pdf and a file that contains the annotation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Xournal** can be used to take notes and annotate PDF files. Annotations are saved in a separate `.xoj` file. If the original file is `example.pdf`, the corresponding Xournal file is named `example.pdf.xoj`.  While Xournal is no longer actively developed, it still appears to be maintained and continues to be available in the package repositories.

**Xournal++** may also be used.  It is a rewrite of Xournal with a slightly modified file format.  Old `.xoj` files can be opened and edited, but will be saved with the new `.xopp` extension.  Xournal++ is available as `xournalpp` in Ubuntu 22.04 and later.

> Is there way to parse xoj files?

`.xoj` and `.xopp` files are gzipped xml files.  They can be uncompressed by adding `.gz` to the filename and running `gzip -d` on them. Then you can use xml or text processing utilities. For example, you can `grep` for notes that were typed as text.

Xournal and Xournal++ can open the uncompressed files, so there is no need to recompress them.  However, files will be compressed when resaved.